# Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Tags: limits

Proving 
 $$\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

I know it can be solved with unit circle but it ends up to become same value.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m102/sinlim.pdf

Comment: Isn't it forced to $1$ by the choice of the size of a  radian?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to evaluate the limit is to use L'Hopital's Rule. Since $\frac{\sin 0}{0}$ is indeterminate, we can apply L'Hopital's Rule.

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x=\cos 0=1$

Comment: This is fine, except that the most common reason for looking at this limit is to help in proving that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$.

Comment: If you are doing this, just notice directly that the limit is the definition of $\displaystyle\left.\frac{d\sin x}{dx}\right|_{x=0}$. The problem then becomes to explain why sine is differentiable at $0$, with derivative $1$.

Comment: The détour by L'Hopital is odd: if you know what is $f'$ then use $f'$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital's Rule states that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)} {g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f'(x)} {g'(x)}.$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)} {x}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos(x)} {1}=\cos(0)=1.$$

Comment: The détour by L'Hopital is odd: if you know what is $f'$ then use $f'$ directly.